Rotating "Witch of Agnesi" about the y-axis (volume of rotation) - Calculus
Working on improper integrals and volumes of rotation for a calculus class.  We integrated the unbounded area under the "Witch of Agnesi":
$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x^2+1)}$ and found the area to be $\pi$
As an extension, I had the students rotate the "witch" about the x-axis using the usual disc method as an improper integral.  It's a tricky integral but we came to a value of $\pi^2/2$.  This value seems to be correct when I crosschecked some online sources and checked software.
Out of curiosity, I attempted to rotate the curve about the y-axis and calculate the volume.  I tried all the tricks I know: inverting the function and integrating "$dy$" and cylindrical shells using "$dx$".  Both of these setups resulted in integrals that diverge.  I feel like the finite area under the unbounded region (pi) should result in a finite volume when rotated about "$y$", especially since it converges when rotating about "$x$".  Perhaps that intuition is flawed?  I couldn't find any online examples for rotating the witch about "$y$".  I'm relatively new working calculus problems at this level.  Any insight is appreciated.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. You get the integral as $\int_0^1\pi(1/y-1)\mathrm{d}y$, right?

Yes, that is what I was showing originally using discs.  I'm showing that diverging with the natural log term in the limit as we approach zero from the right?  Hoping I'm not missing something?

I think you are right to say the integral diverges, here's another approaches integrating using the volume of cylindrical shells. The shell of radius $r$ has height $f(r) = 1/(1+r^2)$, so its volume is
$$ dV =  \frac{2\pi r}{1+r^2} dr. $$
Therefore the integral diverges as:
$$ \int_0^R \frac{2\pi r}{1+r^2} dr = \pi\log (1+r^2). $$
The intuition (for me at least) is that rotating around the $x$-axis "squares" the integrand $f(x)$, which makes it decay faster. Rotating around the $y$-axis multiplies it by $2\pi x$, which changes it to $O(1/x)$ so the integral diverges.

Thank you!  Yes, I got the same setup using cylindrical shells.  I really just needed a sanity check so I appreciate you taking the time to reply.  I think my sticking point is the unbounded area under the curve converges to pi...but yes, I agree the 1/x term has that "harmonic series" flavor...so I think I'm there now in that it diverges.  Thanks again.
